# Change a template to a member function to display all items for a bag

Tags: c++

Question: How do I change a template to a member functions? I'm supposed to write a member function to display all items in the bag. Let me know if you need additional information.

This is a template to display all items in a bag. This is located in my shoppingCart_application.cpp

```
template <class ItemType>
void displayCartItems(const Bag<ItemType> &cart)
{
    vector<ItemType> cartItems;
    cartItems = cart.toVector();
    int numItems = cartItems.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    {
        cout << cartItems[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you change any free function to a member function? This is not much different. I suppose you want to remove the parameter and use `this` instead. Did you try something? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of having a member function filling a `vector` (`toVector()`) add member functions returning iterators. If `Bag<>` keeps the contained elements in a `std` container, adding iterators will be really simple.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you wanted

```
template <class ItemType>
class Bag {
  public:
  void displayItems() const {
    for (auto const & item : this->toVector())
       cout << item << endl;
  }
  // ... rest of Bag class declarations ...
}
```

Comment: depending on what `toVector` returns, this might be UB.